# Use jQuery to change "xlink:href" attribute of SVG element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I'm trying to change the "xlink:href" attribute with a click event, and so far it is partially working. This is what I'm doing

HTML:

```
 <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow editIcon" data-iconpos="top" data-transition="none" style="text-align:center">
<svg class="icon icon-pencil">
<use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#icon-pencil">   </use>
</svg>
</a>
```

JS:

```
 $('a.editIcon').on('click', function () {


 if ($("a.editIcon svg").attr('class') == 'icon icon-pencil') {
     $("a.editIcon svg").attr("class", "icon icon-floppy-disk");
     $("a.editIcon svg use").attr("xlink:href", "#icon-floppy-disk");


 } else {
     myFunctionCall();
     $("a.editIcon svg").attr("class", "icon icon-pencil");
     $("a.editIcon svg use").attr("xlink:href", "#icon-pencil");



 }

 });
```

What is happening is that I'm able to change the class without any problems, but the "xlink:href" attribute doesn't change, instead, leaves the old one ("#icon-pencil"), and adds a new "href" attribute (href="#icon-floppy-disk"):

```
<svg class="icon icon-floppy-disk">
<use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#icon-pencil" href="#icon-floppy-disk"></use>
</svg>
```

What am I missing here? Thanks!

Comment: Try placing two backslashes before the `:`: `\\:` or use `$('[xlink\\:href]')` instead.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22081551/svg-image-turns-black-after-updating-his-path-via-jquery/22081746

Comment: Unless there is a plugin I dont think jQuery will let you set namespaced attributes. You will probaly need to resort to using the native DOM functions: `$("a.editIcon svg use").get(0).setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href', '#icon-pencil');`

Comment: Thanks all for the help. Actually, both @Dr. Molle and @prodigitalson have the same effect, it leaves it with `xlink:href="#icon-pencil" href="#icon-floppy-disk`. I guess I'll have to find another way, probably replaceWith() and replace the whole thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had this same question today and after searching around I found two solutions that worked. As suggested by @Dr.Molle and @prodigitalson in this question's comments, I was able to use:`_HTMLNode_.setAttributeNS()` to fix my problem but I am not sure why this solution failed to work for you @cubanGuy.

After digging through SVG Spec, I learned that `xlink:href` is deprecated in favor of using a non-namespaced `href` attribute. The `href` attribute (on SVG elements) is represented with a SVGAnimatedString object [(used to reflect an animatable string attribute)](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/types.html#InterfaceSVGAnimatedString) which has two properties:

```
interface SVGAnimatedString {
         attribute DOMString baseVal;
readonly attribute DOMString animVal;
};
```

This enables us to change the value of the `href` attribute by setting `_HTMLNode_.href.baseVal` which also changes the `xlink:href` attribute because the baseVal setter does the following:

> If the `href` attribute is not present, the SVGAnimatedString object is defined to additionally reflect the deprecated `xlink:href` attribute if the deprecated attribute is present. Then it sets that deprecated attribute to the specified value.

Since the namespaced attribute is deprecated I recommend that `_HTMLNode_.href.baseVal` be used in favor of `_HTMLNode_.setAttributeNS()` when supporting modern browsers. If you want to see them in action I created a snippet that demonstrates both methods working below:

```js
var svgElement1 = document.getElementById("editIcon1");
svgElement1.onclick = function () {
 var useElement = this.getElementsByTagName("use")[0];
   if (this.className === 'icon icon-locked') {
       this.className = "icon icon-unlocked";
       useElement.href.baseVal = "#unlocked";
   } else {
       this.className = "icon icon-locked";
       useElement.href.baseVal = "#locked";
   }
 }
 var svgElement2 = document.getElementById("editIcon2");
svgElement2.onclick = function () {
 var useElement = this.getElementsByTagName("use")[0];
   if (this.className === 'icon icon-locked') {
       this.className = "icon icon-unlocked";
       useElement.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href', '#unlocked');
   } else {
       this.className = "icon icon-locked";
       useElement.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href', '#locked');
   }
 }
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svg-icons">
  <symbol viewBox="0 0 24 24" id="unlocked">
    <path d="M18,9h-1V7c0-2.8-2.2-5-5-5S7,4.2,7,7h1.9c0-1.7,1.4-3.1,3.1-3.1s3.1,1.4,3.1,3.1v2H6c-1.1,0-2,0.9-2,2v9c0,1.1,0.9,2,2,2
             h12c1.1,0,2-0.9,2-2v-9C20,9.9,19.1,9,18,9z"></path>
  </symbol>
  <symbol viewBox="0 0 24 24" id="locked">
    <path d="M18,9h-1V7c0-2.8-2.2-5-5-5S7,4.2,7,7v2H6c-1.1,0-2,0.9-2,2v9c0,1.1,0.9,2,2,2h12c1.1,0,2-0.9,2-2v-9C20,9.9,19.1,9,18,9z
             M15.1,9H8.9V7c0-1.7,1.4-3.1,3.1-3.1s3.1,1.4,3.1,3.1V9z"></path>
  </symbol>
</svg>
  
<div>
  <a href="#" id="editIcon1">this is test 1
    <svg class="icon icon-locked">
      <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#unlocked">   </use>
    </svg>
  </a>
</div>
<div>
  <a href="#" id="editIcon2">this is test 2
    <svg class="icon icon-locked">
      <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#unlocked"></use>
    </svg>
  </a>
</div>
```

Here is a working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ybtq9e03/

I hope this helps!